# How to resolve Vsam File status error code 93?

Tags: mainframe, cics, vsam

When I am trying to access a Vsam Sequential dataset(which is also opened in CICS) from batch, I use EXTEND mode to open the file and append some data to it.

Earlier it was working fine. All of a sudden , it is not working now and I am getting File status : 93  error code which means "Resource not available".

```
OPEN EXTEND <filename>
```

Foe KSDS datasets I have used EXCI(external CICS Interface) calls to access from batch even though it was opened in Online.

But I do not know how to do the same for ESDS.

Could someone help me to resolve this error.

Comment: What is the purpose of this ESDS?

Comment: @BillWoodger  To update some records in it. It is an audit file

Comment: It doesn't sound like much of an audit file if you are going to update records in it, does it?

Comment: @BillWoodger  Yeah. thats right.It's a mistake on my part. I am not updating the records. I need to append  a new record on each batch run.

Comment: Well, you either do that within the existing process; or you use EXCI again; or you keep your batch-file separately, physically, from the CICS file. What you can't do is just OPEN it, like you couldn't do with the KSDS.

Comment: @BillWoodger I have couple of queries here. 1) Do you mean the existing process as "Opening the file with EXTEND mode".  2) How to use the EXCI for ESDS. Could you please help with some sample?    Because I do not know what should be given for Key and Keylength attributes.

Comment: I'm assuming you can use EXCI to add records to an ESDS. I've never tried. If you OPEN EXTEND in your batch program, you're going to need the dataset closed to CICS. Why do you want to add to a CICS audit file from batch anyway?

Comment: The batch is having the same functionality as online. Our business requirements are such that it is necessary for batch to run when CICS is up and running.

Comment: You are presumably accessing a CICS program with EXCI to do the KSDS. You need to access a different program to do the ESDS. You may need to write, or get written. that program. You won't be able to do it with any OPEN in COBOL whilst the dataset is open to CICS. Unless you want to get really tortuous.